# C++ extern keyword on functions. Why no just include the header file?

Tags: c++, linker, extern

If I understand it correctly this means

```
extern void foo();
```

that the function foo is declared in another translation unit.

1) Why not just #include the header in which this function is declared?

2) How does the linker know where to look for function at linking time?

edit: Maybe I should clarify that the above declaration is then followed by using the function

```
foo();
```

It is never defined in this translation unit.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1) It may not have a header file. But yes, in general, for large projects, you should have a header file if multiple translation units are going to use that function (don't repeat yourself).

2) The linker searches through all the object files and libraries it was told about to find functions and other symbols.

Comment: Does this mean that you can call a modules internal functions (let's assume the source is not available) if you know the function's signature?

Comment: If the functions have external linkage, then yes. However you won't be able to call functions declared in an unnamed namespace or declared static (unless you know how your compiler/linker mangles names).

Comment: So, why can't we just declare it without `extern` like header files usually do? I guess, it will link it successfully later on when we pass a path to library containing that implementation, am I wrong?

Answer (score 29):

No, this means that function `foo` is declared with *external linkage*. External linkage means that name `foo` refers to the same function in the entire program. Where the function is defined does not matter. It can be defined in this translation unit. It can be defined in other translation unit.

Using `extern` keyword as shown in your example is superfluous. Functions always have external linkage by default. The above is 100% equivalent to just

```
void foo();
```

As for the linker, when the linker links the program together it simply looks *everywhere*. It looks through all definitions until it finds the definition for `foo`.

Answer (score 20):

As others have already stated, the `extern` keyword is used to state the name (a variable or function) has external linkage, meaning the name refers to the same object in the entire program. Also, this is the default for variables and functions defined at the file scope, so this usage is superfluous.

There's another use of the extern keyword that goes like this:

```
extern "C" void foo();
```

This means the function `foo` will be linked using the C conventions for linkage (maybe because this is a function defined in a C library or is a function intended to be called by C programs).

Comment: `for variables and functions defined at the file scope, so this usage is superfluous` that statement is not accurate. For non-const global variables `extern` keyword makes difference telling the compiler that current line is not definition (if explicit definition is omitted)

Answer (score 9):

It already means that without the extern keyword.  Functions have external linkage by default, unless you declare them static.

Using function prototypes is okay but it is easy get it wrong.  The linker error you'll get isn't that easy to diagnose when you redefine the function implementation.  The linker doesn't know where to look, it is your job to give it an object file that contains the function definition to keep it happy.

Comment: What about a static function in a class?

Answer (score 2):

1) I don't know why I'd need this for a function. Maybe someone else can step in.

2) The linker determines this by going through all object files and checking the symbols inside each object file. I assume that depending on your linker, the exact search order might vary.

For GNU binutils' ld all object files and libraries that appear in the linker command line after the object containing the missing symbol are searched from left to right and the first found symbol is picked.

*Example 1:*

- a.o -- uses foo(), bar()
- liba -- provides bar()
- libb -- provides foo()

$> ld a.o -la -lb

will result in a.o being searched for undefined symbols. Thereafter ld will go through the libs from left to right to search for these symbols and will find bar in liba and foo in libb.

This may lead to strange problems upon circular dependencies:

*Example 2:*

- a.o -- uses bar()
- liba -- provides bar(), uses foo()
- libb -- provides foo(), uses bar()

Now, there is a circular dependency between liba and libb and linking will fail:

$> ld a.o -la -lb

because when searching through the undefined symbols in libb, ld will determine that there is no other lib *to the right of -lb* that provides this symbol. This may be fixed in at least two ways:

1) link liba twice:
$> ld a.o -la -lb -la

2) use ld's grouping feature
$> ld a.o --start-group -la -lb --end-group

In case 2), the grouping tells ld to search through all symbols in all libs belonging to this group.