# why function didnt need extern, but variable does

Tags: c++, function, variables, extern

Sorry guys I know my english is bad, but i made examples so that my question is more clearer.
**a.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void funcfoo(){
    cout << "test only" << endl;
}

int varfoo = 10;
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern void funcfoo();

extern int varfoo;

int main(){

    funcfoo();

    cout << varfoo;

    return 0;
}
```

**Then I compile it like this "cl b.cpp a.cpp"**
My question is. How come when I remove the "extern keyword before void funcfoo()" it works fine, but when i remove the extern keyword
before int var foo I get an error?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604202/c-extern-keyword-on-functions-why-no-just-include-the-header-file -- functions have external linkage by default; the keyword is redundant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is what each one of the lines of code means. `int varfoo` is a **definition** of a variable, while `void funcfoo()` is only a **declaration**. You can provide multiple declarations of an entity, but only one *definition*. The syntax to provide a *declaration* and only a *declaration* of a variable is by adding the `extern` keyword: `extern int varfoo;` is a *declaration*

---

> 3.1 [basic.def]/2 A declaration is a definition unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body (8.4), it contains the extern specifier (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification25 (7.5) and neither an initializer nor a function body [...]

Comment: I think definition is like int varfoo = value;, then int varfoo; is declaration. Am I wroong?

Comment: int varfoo; <--- I think this is declaration not definition

Comment: @user1628256: Yes you are. `int varfoo;` is a definition without initialization, `int varfoo = value;` is a definition with initialization.

Comment: int varfoo = value; <---- I think this one is declare then define. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user1628256 `int var;` <-- (definition), `var = 5;` <-- definition

Comment: void funcfoo(){ cout << "test only" << endl; } <--- this is definition right?

Comment: It's a definition. Note: in global scope `int varfoo;` is with initialization.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I am not sure about it. Variables with static storage duration are value initialized *before* any other initialization takes place, but that does not mean that the declaration has an *initializer* (it does not have one).

Comment: so there is no declaration of a variable only a function?

Comment: @user1628256: `extern int varfoo;` **is** a declaration of a variable.

Comment: ok lets just forget about extern, lets say we only have 1 .cpp file....so int varfoo you said it is definition right?

Comment: @user1628256: Yes, `int varfoo;` is a definition

Comment: @David: why extern int varfoo; becomes a declaration?

Comment: @user1628256: Because that is how the language goes... read the quote from the standard in the answer.

Comment: @user1628256 Before I answer that question, can you please accept this answer by clicking on the check mark next to it? It helps a lot.

Comment: @user1628256: this is really *confusing*. I feel like I have split personality (with the other David). Anyway: what did you not understand from my last comment? Did you read the quote from the standard?

Comment: @user1628256 You know that it's a declaration of a variable when you see: `int a;`. But it's a *definition* of a variable when you see: `a = 3` later on. You can also do this: `int a = 5;`. I am defining a new variable called `a` which I am initializing with the number 5.  It doesn't matter if you see `extern` in front. If it's not being initialized, it is a declaration.

Comment: @david I understand the declaration and definition with function. The quote from the standard that you post is about functions right?. What I dont get is about variable you said that "int varfoo" is definition, then extern "int varfoo" is declaration. I dont get why with extern it becomes a declaration.

Comment: @user1628256: No, it is about *declarations* in general. Note that the last sentence quoted contains: *and neither an initializer nor a function body*. You cannot provide an *initailizer* for a function, as you cannot provide a function body for a variable.

Comment: @david "int varfoo is a definition of a variable" <--- you said this

Comment: @user1628256: Yes, `int varfoo;` **is** a **definition** and a **declaration**. `extern int varfoo;` is a **declaration** but not a **definition**. You keep asking the same once and again, but I don't understand what is it that confuses you.

Comment: @david I already know the simple answer to my question "function names are made visible to the linker by default". But I got confuse with these definition and declaration.

Comment: Please take this conversation to the chat room. -- http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10 Or make your own

Comment: you said int a; is a declaration then later a = 3 is definition. How come int varfoo is a definition i doesnt have a value.

Comment: @user1628256: You are confusing me (*David Rodriguez*) with someone else (*David*). I never said `int a;` is a *declaration* (it is, but it is also a *definition*).

Comment: @david You know that it's a declaration of a variable when you see: int a;. But it's a definition of a variable when you see: a = 3 later on <-- coming from you

Comment: @david ok even though I dont get it I want to thank you. Im sleepy now so maybe thats part of the reason why I dont understand it.

Comment: @user1628256: Ignore that whole comment (note that the name of the commenter is 'David' --without any trailing last names...) That is misleading. `int a` **is** a definition, regardless of `= 3`. It is a declaration and not a definition if and only if `extern` is present and no initializer is present.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: The question was regarding the comment *Note: in global scope int varfoo; is with initialization*. There is a slight difference between there being an initializer and the variable being initialized. A variable with static storage duration will be value initialized, irrespective of the presence of an *initializer*. The declaration `int varfoo;` at namespace level does not contain an *initializer* even if it is guaranteed to be initialized to 0.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: ughmmhuhvomit.. I think you're saying the same thing, but with the correct terminology. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you remove the `extern` from `extern void funcfoo();` you are forward declaring it so you're code below will know what `funcfoo()` is.  If you were to do that to a variable, you would actually be instantiating it and would conflict with your other file. Hence the `extern` is saying "it exists, trust me ;)" that it gets resolved from your other file.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about it is that when you do int varfoo memory is allocated to hold the variable so it is both a definition and a declaration, when you do int foo() the function is declared but not defined so in a way the memory is not allocated. For functions the linkage is external by default so removing it doesn't matter but for the variable, if you say extern int varfoo the compiler will not allocate memory for it --it will assume that the variable is defined somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be late, but I hope this helps in some way. Check the link below and it ll give an idea of what extern is and how it works.

```
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/
```

Thank you